# Is my parse tableview searching inefficient (swift / objectiveC)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

So i have a bunch of fields in my parse server and I have a tableview in my iOS app. For each cell there is a bunch of data like I said before. But the problem is that I want to allow a user to be able to search that data. My question is, if I have lets say 50,000 pfobjects of listings and my parse server and a user is searching this many fields, is it going to be extremely expensive or are searches not that expensive. Keep in mind that everything searched is lowercased so it won't be a problem. Here is my code. I have 31 fields I'm searching text. Is this bad to do. Will it ramp up a lot of bills on my server side if I have hundreds of thousands of users. Heres is my code.

```
var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!
             query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
            let fiel1 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field1.whereKey("field one", contains: search)
            let field2 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field2.whereKey("field two", contains: search)
            let field3 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field3.whereKey("field three", contains: search)
            let field4 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field3.whereKey("field four", contains: search)
            let field5 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field5.whereKey("field 5", contains: search)
            let field6 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field6.whereKey("field 6", contains: search)
            let field7 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field7.whereKey("field 7", contains: search)
            let field8 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field8.whereKey("field 8", contains: search)
            let field9 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field9.whereKey("field 9", contains: search)
            let field10 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field10.whereKey("field 10", contains: search)
            let field11 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field11.whereKey("field 11", contains: search)
            let field12 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field12.whereKey("field 12", contains: search)
            let field13 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field13.whereKey("field 13", contains: search)
            let field14 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field14.whereKey("field 14", contains: search)
            let field15 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field15.whereKey("field 15", contains: search)
            let field16 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field16.whereKey("field 16", contains: search)
            let field17 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field17.whereKey("field 17", contains: search)
            let field18 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field18.whereKey("field 18", contains: search)
            let field19 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field19.whereKey("field 19", contains: search)
            let field20 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field20.whereKey("field 20", contains: search)
            let field21 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field21.whereKey("field 21", contains: search)
            let field22 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field22.whereKey("field 22", contains: search)
            let field23 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field23.whereKey("field 23", contains: search)
            let field24 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field24.whereKey("field 24", contains: search)
            let field25 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field25.whereKey("field 25", contains: search)
            let field26 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field26.whereKey("field 26", contains: search)
            let field27 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field27.whereKey("field 27", contains: search)
            let field28 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field28.whereKey("field 28", contains: search)
            let field29 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field29.whereKey("field 29", contains: search)
            let field30 = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            field30.whereKey("field 30", contains: search)
            let objectId = PFQuery(className: "Real Estate")
            objectId.whereKey("objectId", contains: search)
            query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21, field22, field23, field24, field25, field26, field27, field28, field29, field30, objectId])
```

Comment: The code is definitely inefficient. Why don't you use an array to hold fields?

Comment: @Sulthan what do you mean, could you show me how I would do that. The only reason I keep the fields separated is because I have to then retrieve the data and put them in different labels.

Comment: @Sulthan can you still access the fields and put each text from each field in a label. And if so, could you show me how I would save, retrieve and search the text in a holding array or point me to another stack overflow page where I could see that.

Comment: The only trick to it is to keep the labels in an array (e.g. an `IBOutlet` collection). That's a rather different question though.

Comment: @Sulthan could you show me how I would save, retrieve and search labels from an array. I haven't heard about this before and I'm intrigued.

Comment: @Sulthan do you have a Skype so I can show you my project. My project is fairly large and is scattered in very large pieces. Could i Skype you and show you the project myself.

Comment: @Sulthan Two questions, Can't I just access an index in the array and set the label to that text instead of setting all the labels in an IBOutlet collection.

Comment: @Sulthan and second is when, I try to edit one field, I have to resave the entire array right.